# A simple calculation in php.. I'm doing it wrong?

Tags: php

I do not understand php:

```
 echo -0.01-0.02-0.16+0.01+0.01+0.17;
```

result 2.7755575615629E-17
correctly = 0 !

Comment: Please read `Warning` section in http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: [Read, learn and understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) If you're going to be working with floating point values on computers in any language, this is something that you really need to know

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3):

E-17 really means x 10 ^ (-17).

According to the computer, which suffers from precision errors at the far end of decimal floating point numbers, it is calculating your answer to be 0.00000000000000002775557...

If you don't need that sort of precision, you can force rounding to a certain accuracy:

```
echo round(-0.01-0.02-0.16+0.01+0.01+0.17, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you got is accurate answer according to BODMAS rule if you want round up answer than just use `round()` function of PHP. You will get you answer.

```
  echo round(-0.01-0.02-0.16+0.01+0.01+0.17, 8);
```

Comment: well thank you,
I understand if it's dividing
But when counting?
Each operation rounds?